# print elements in an array with a delimiter

Tags: python, arrays

I am new to Python and I have become stuck with printing the elements of an array separated by a delimiter. My array consists of 60 000 odd rows with 26 elements per row, some of the elements only contain numbers, while others contain an assortment of characters including special characters.
Example:

```
a[0] = [abc,123,a1b2c3,*wewqe,...] 
a[1] = [098i,qwerty,123qwe,xx-u,...]
```

I would like the output to be(without a "|" after the last element and each row on their own line:

```
abc|123|a1b2c3|*wewqe,...
098i|qwerty|123qwe|xx-u,...
```

I have tried the following, but they do not work:

```
for row in results :
    length = len(row)
    print("")#throw in a new line
    print ("Number of elements: " + str(length))
    print '|'.join((str(row)))
```

And this:

```
for row in results :
    length = len(row)
    print("")#throw in a new line
    print ("Number of elements: " + str(length))
    for item in row:
            print '|'.join(str(item))
```

And this:

```
 for row in results :
    length = len(row)
    print("")#throw in a new line
    print ("Number of elements: " + str(length))
    for item in row:
    print item,
```

All of the above produces results, but not the results I would like. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi Greg, are you sure your elements are not strings? if not, what is wewqe in your first array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print '|'.join(map(str, row))
```

`join` takes a sequence of strings. `row` is a sequence of... something, so `map(str, row)` turns it into a sequence of strings. If the elements of `row` are already strings (and they should be), you can just do

```
print '|'.join(row)
```

Comment: Thanks!! Works like a Charm, I was trying `print '|'.join((str(row)))`

Comment: This works nicely for me as I wanted a csv like formatting with a comma separator.

Comment: @DavidJung: If you want CSV, you should probably check out the [csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Comment: @user2357112 Great. Seems even the previous version of Python has the module (I’m using 3.5.5). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your arrays contain strings. You might want to edit your post accordingly.
You can do:

```
a = [ 'abc','123','a1b2c3','*wewqe' ]
output = '|'.join(a)
print output
```

output:

```
abc|123|a1b2c3|*wewqe
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> ",".join(["a", "b", "c"])
'a,b,c'
```

This will help you to join array